# How can I display an Overlay as part of a statefulWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've created an `Overlay` to display a dropdown menu on top of my screen.  I originally made this widget as a `StatelessWidget` and it worked perfectly

```
class ShowNotificationIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  ShowNotificationIcon({Key? key});
  
  bool isDropdownOpened = false;
  late OverlayEntry floatingDropdown;
  late Offset position;

  Positioned theDropDown(){
    return
      Positioned(
        top: position.dy,
        left: 50.0,
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child:
            //new Icon(Icons.warning, color: Colors.purple),
            Column(children: [
              Text('Test!'),
            ],)),
      );
  }


  void show(BuildContext context) async {

    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: _build);

    final container = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    position = container.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    floatingDropdown = overlayEntry;
    Overlay.of(context)?.insert(floatingDropdown);

    isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;

  }

  Widget _build(BuildContext context){
    return Stack(
      children: [

        Positioned.fill(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                (...)
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            )
        ),

        theDropDown()

      ],
    );
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

I would call it as follows:

```
ShowNotificationIcon _icon = ShowNotificationIcon();
_icon.show(context);
```

Now I need to add animations to it, so I have to convert it to a `StatefulWidget`, which I did as follows:

```
class ShowNotificationIcon extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ShowNotificationIcon({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _ShowNotificationIconState createState() => _ShowNotificationIconState();
}

class _ShowNotificationIconState extends ConsumerState<ShowNotificationIcon> {


  bool isDropdownOpened = false;
  late OverlayEntry floatingDropdown;
  late Offset position;

  void initState(){
    super.initState();
  }

  void dispose(){
    super.dispose();
  }

  Positioned theDropDown(){
    return
      Positioned(
        top: position.dy,
        left: 50.0,
        child: Material(
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child:
            //new Icon(Icons.warning, color: Colors.purple),
            Column(children: [
              Text('Test!'),
            ],)),
      );
  }


  void show(BuildContext context) async {

    OverlayEntry overlayEntry = OverlayEntry(builder: _build);

    final container = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    position = container.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);

    floatingDropdown = overlayEntry;
    Overlay.of(context)?.insert(floatingDropdown);

    isDropdownOpened = !isDropdownOpened;

  }

  Widget _build(BuildContext context){
    return Stack(
      children: [

        Positioned.fill(
            child: GestureDetector(
              onTap: () {
                (...)
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.transparent,
              ),
            )
        ),

        theDropDown()

      ],
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // TODO: implement build
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }
}
```

But now that its stateful I cannot call it with the way I did before

```
ShowNotificationIcon _icon = ShowNotificationIcon();
_icon.show(context);
```

That doesn't work anymore.

I can't understand how to call it within a function?  Now that its `Stateful`, I can't seem to reach that function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should try applying [state management approach](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

In your case I would use **ValueNotifier() like this:**

```dart
//initialize somewhere your ValueNotifier
ValueNotifier<bool> playAnimation = ValueNotifier(false);

//add ValueNotifier argument to ShowNotificationIcon constructor
class ShowNotificationIcon extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const ShowNotificationIcon({Key? key, this.playAnimation}) : super(key: key);

  final ValueNotifier<bool> playAnimation;

  @override
  _ShowNotificationIconState createState() => _ShowNotificationIconState();
}

//then pass this instance to your StatefulWidget
ShowNotificationIcon(playAnimation);

//from _ShowNotificationIconState access instance with widget.playAnimation
//then you add a listener, so when the value changes, you can play your animations
class _ShowNotificationIconState extends ConsumerState<ShowNotificationIcon> {
  widget.playAnimation.addListener(() {
    if(widget.playAnimation.value){ show(); playAnimation.value = false; }
  });
}

//when you want the animation to play:
playAnimation.value = true;
```

Comment: But how do you call the ShowNotificationIconState?  Its not included in the widget tree anywhere, since its basically an overlay that gets called if someone taps on a button.  With the above stateless widget approach, it was called by directly accessing the `.show` function, but it seems I cannot access it with a stateful approach?

Comment: is `ShowNotificationIcon` included somewhere in the widget tree?

Comment: @Eimentas G nope

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but whats the point then of having your ShowNotication function extend StatufulWidget? Couldn't you just make it a normal function and then call your wanted `.show` method?